# What does %% do in printf?

Tags: c, io

Given the following program in C,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{ 
    printf(" \"Books %% OR %% apparels\""); 
    getchar(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

The program prints Books % OR % apparels, 
I would like to know the significance of %%, because it looks to be unnecessary.

Comment: The compiler has nothing to do with this. Read 'man printf'.

Comment: It is an escape sequence. As % has special meaning in printf type functions, to print the literal %, you type %% to prevent it from being interpreted as starting a conversion fmt.

Comment: So, what does your favorite C book say about the meaning of `%` in `printf` format string? Does it by any chance say anything about `%` character having any special meaning? About it being treated differently from other characters?

Comment: @gnometorule We can use `\%` to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%` indicates a format escape sequence used for formatting the variables passed to `printf()`.

So you have to escape it to print the `%` character.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

---

If you replace the `%%` to `%`, like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf(" \"Books % OR % apparels\"");
    return 0;
}
```

There are two escape sequences to `printf()`:

1. `"% O"`

   [guesswork] This does not yields to a valid escape sequence so `printf()` disregards it and print it as is.
2. `"% a"`

   `printf()` will try to get a `float` from the **empty** parameter list and print it  as "Hexadecimal floating point, lowercase" (`%a`, see the above webpage). Due to C calling convention (disclaimer: I'm not an expert on this), some garbage from memory is used and that explains the result.

Actually my compiler (gcc 4.4.3) issued warnings to both:

```
$ gcc a.c
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:3: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘O’ in format
a.c:3: warning: too few arguments for format
```

Comment: I checked it out, thanks.
However, I am confused on this:
If we replace "%%" with "%" 
The output is"Books % OR -0x1.a9288p-8pparels"
Why that behavior?